# php calling a string in an array creates empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, insert

Currently I have this:

```
<?php
$fn = "file.txt";
$file = file_get_contents("./$fn");
$array = array($file);
?>
```

An example of whats in the text file:

```
array(1,4,3,2),array(3,2,1,2),array(5,6,7,8)
```

However when I print the array or even sizeof($array) it is empty.  Whats the deal?

Answer (score 0):

The content of your file is plain text not array data structures. You'll have to parse the content yourself. Here is one way of doing it:

```
$file_content = "array(1,4,3,2),array(3,2,1,2),array(5,6,7,8)";

$matches = [];
$arrays = [];
if (preg_match_all('~array\(((?:(?:\d+),?)*)\),?~', $file_content, $matches)) {
    $arrays = array_map(function ($array) { return explode(',', $array); }, $matches[1]);
}
```

`$arrays` now contains arrays as you would expect and you can use `count()` to check their size.

If you know that your file always contain arrays another way to do it is by using eval.

#### Another approach

```
eval('$arrays2 = [' . $file_content . '];');
```

Now `$arrays2` contains the same arrays. There is one subtle difference. The former approach does not cast the values to integers whereas eval does.

Warning: Only use eval() if are 100% sure that you know what goes into the function. Also note that this approach will fail on bad data, whereas the former is a little more resilient.